# How to get numbers out of string into array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have strings like
`'156p1m2s10c'`
`'15p13m22s3c'`
`'1644p31m142s3c'`

out of which I want to get all numerics separately.

An array will also work like:

```
156  
--
1
--
2
--
33
```

How to do it using Jquery. I tried code mentioned below, but it's all going wrong.

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "156p1m2s33c";
    var prodId = cust_code.substring(0, url.indexOf('p'));
    var metalId = cust_code.substring(url.indexOf('p') + 1, url.indexOf('m'));
    var prodId = cust_code.substring(url.indexOf('m') + 1, url.indexOf('s'));
}
```

What is wrong in the code?

Comment: Your example has no jquery in it, nor should it.

Comment: if you want to stick to your way of coding make a function with the string as a parameter and apply your substrings to it ! in your example you use prodId twice which is wrong. To return a result use the keyword return and return an object or an array which allows you to return several "variables" in your function. but the use of str.match id far better :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [String#match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a RegExp. You can use Array#map afterwards to convert the strings to numbers if needed.

```js
var str = '156p1m2s33c';

var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g);

console.log(numbers);
```

What's wrong in your code:

1. `cust_code` and `url` are not part of the function. Refer to `str`.
2. You declare `prodId` twice.
3. You don't handle the number between "s" and "c".
4. You are doing a lot of duplicated search (index of p, index of m, etc...).
5. Your function doesn't return anything, or do anything with the results.
6. Using regular expressions is more fitting for this case.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = "156p1m2s33c";
    var pI = str.indexOf('p');
    var mI = str.indexOf('m');
    var sI = str.indexOf('s');
    var cI = str.indexOf('c');
    
    var prodId = str.substring(0, pI);
    var metalId = str.substring(pI + 1, mI);
    var anotherId1 = str.substring(mI + 1, sI);
    var anotherId2 = str.substring(sI + 1, cI);
    
    return [prodId, metalId, anotherId1, anotherId2];
}

console.log(myFunction());
```